# Lucene index HTML Headings

Tags: java, html, lucene

I want to index HTML files and be able to jump to the corresponding heading after receiving my search results.

I currently use a HTMLStripCharFilter for parsing my files.

```
public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  public MyAnalyzer() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  protected Reader initReader(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    return new HTMLStripCharFilter(reader);
  }

  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
    StandardTokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(source);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
  }
}
```

The method indexMyFile gets the path to one HTML file and creates the index, but it currently only stores the file name.

```
private static void indexMyFile(IndexWriter writer, Path file,
  long lastModified) throws IOException {
try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
  Document doc = new Document();

  Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.toString(),
      Field.Store.YES);
  doc.add(pathField);
  doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

  writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

My solution was to add a new TextField to this Lucene Document, but I currently don't know the headings in this point of the code.
Is there a way of using Lucene, so I can link the content to the current heading and file name? Or do I have to use JSoup or JTidy and pass my indexMyFile Method the text after headings and create a Lucene Document for each heading, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576119/lucene-indexing-of-html-files#12576420)?

Answer (score 0):

I used [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse the HTML tags. Then instead of indexing the whole file, I created a Document for each heading containing several fields:

```
private void indexString(Path path, String title, String heading,
  String content) throws IOException {
  Document doc = new Document();

  doc.add(new Field("title", title, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
  doc.add(new Field("heading", heading, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
  doc.add(new StringField("path", path.toString(), Field.Store.YES));
  doc.add(new StringField("urlHeading", urlHeading, Field.Store.YES));
  doc.add(new TextField("contents", content, Store.NO));
  writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```